# how to connect application desktop with mysql database in two pc or more

Tags: mysql, database, remote-access

```
def Db_connect(self):
    host=self.lineEdit_55.text()
    user=self.lineEdit_59.text()
    password=self.lineEdit_60.text()
    db=self.lineEdit_61.text()

    self.db=MySQLdb.connect(host='{}'.format(host), user='{}'.format(user), password='{}'.format(password), db='{}'.format(db))
    self.cur = self.db.cursor()
```

I am using this code to configure user extension but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQLdb.connect only uses text

```
self.db=MySQLdb.connect('{}'.format(host), '{}'.format(user), '{}'.format(password), '{}'.format(db))
```

Like

```
db = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pyqt5')
```

Comment: thanks for answer i take this error if not give anny argument  in linEdit

Comment: MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'hp'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Comment: that is more complicated, because this can have multiple causes. First check mysql error log, then check if the user **hp** has access to the database(check also with mysqlclient) further it makes a difference if local host or remote access, there are already a lot of answer for this problems.

Comment: My problem is that the program does not work in order for the user to enter the values. To connect to the database the values must be entered in the code and I want to enter them by the user

Comment: have tried tkinter which gives you widgets ti enter data, and then use it to connect, if you don't need a gui see this tutorial https://stackabuse.com/getting-user-input-in-python/ there are also Forms https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/51564/forms.LoginForm